# How to detect, prevent, and fix java windows registry corruption (i.e. "could not find java.dll")

Tags: java, registry

**Problem: java.exe complains about dll**

We use a tool that copies-and-renames java.exe to a temp directory, i.e. /path/to/some/dir/java_foo_application.exe. [The tool is 'Yet Another Java Service Wrapper' or YAJSW. It copies-and-renames so that meaningful names show in the windows task manager ]

On some machines, corrupt java entries in the windows registry give this error when running this copied java.exe:

```
Error opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

**Solved Once Before: Uninstall and reinstall**

I've had this problem once before:  nd solved it by uninstalling all jdk's -- using windows "add remove programs"-- and reinstalling a newer version of java.

Note that one of the jdk's would not uninstall. I  had to download special registry cleaner from microsoft to force uninstallation.

**My question: Detect and Prevent?**

- How can one tell in advance whether a system has corrupt java registry entries?
- How to prevent this corruption for the future?
- Any other ways to fix this aside from uninstalling and reinstalling the jdk's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what the real problem, download two jar files:

[first](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20584933/wrapper.jar) and [second](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20584933/wrapperApp.jar)

remember to set:
wrapper.console.pipestreams = true

Described on [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yajsw/forums/forum/810311/topic/5162319) page

The Wrapper log file shows me this trace:

-set state RESTART_START->RUNNING

-Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.5', but '1.6' is required.

-Error: could not find java.dll

-Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment.
process terminated
Controller State: WAITING -> PROCESS_KILLED

**I solve my problem reinstalling System JRE 1.6.**

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with javaw you could use an executable wrapper to start your application. See for example [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html) or [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/features.php).

Comment: to clarify: we do not use javaw. We're using a java service wrapper which wraps a windows service around the application.

Comment: exe4j and JSmooth are able to wrap a Windows service. Also exe4j has an heuristic to locate the JRE on the system, so if the registry is broken it can still find the runtime at known locations, or based on an environment variable.